# Why value is lost while sorting a table with javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am trying to sort a table with JavaScript.

```
function test() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

    var allRow = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');

    var ar = new Array();
    for(var i = 1; i < allRow.length; i++) {
        ar[i - 1] = allRow[i];
    }

    //sort the data according to number
    ar.sort(function(l, r) {
        var num1 = parseInt(l.childNodes[1].innerHTML);
        var num2 = parseInt(r.childNodes[1].innerHTML);
        return (num1 > num2) ? 1 : ((num1 < num2) ? -1 : 0);
    });
    //assigning the sorted data in the table
    for(var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        allRow[i + 1].innerHTML = ar[i].innerHTML;
    }
}
```

But when I am trying to assigning the sorted data in the table somehow it does not. But If I keep the `ar` data in a new array and then assign that in `allRow` it does. I am totally newbie in this. So can anyone please tell me why is this happening?

```
var tmp = new Array();
for(var i = 0 ; i<ar.length ; i++){
    tmp[i] = ar[i].innerHTML;
}

for(var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    allRow[i + 1].innerHTML = tmp[i];
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to post an example on jsFiddle?

Comment: The sort function can just return `num1 - num2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you copy the elements to the `ar` array you are not making copies of the elements, you are only copying the references to the elements. The `ar` array doesn't contain elements with the same content as the `allRow` array, it contains *the same* elements.

When you change the content of an element in the `allRow` array, it will change in the `ar` array also, as it's the same element.

When you have sorted the array, read the `innerHTML` from all rows, then you can write them back:

```
for(var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
  ar[i] = ar[i].innerHTML;
}
for(var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
  allRow[i + 1].innerHTML = ar[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why u r override sort function with your own.When sort give functionality of sorting any kind of data like numeric , alphabetical an etc...

make it simple  like this

```
function test() {

        var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        var allRow = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');            
        var ar = new Array();

        for(var i = 1; i <= allRow.length; i++) {               
             ar[i-1]=table.rows[i-1].cells[0].innerHTML;                
        }           
        ar.sort();
        //assigning the sorted data in the table
        for(var i = 1; i <= allRow.length; i++) {               
             table.rows[i-1].cells[0].innerHTML=ar[i-1];

        }

   }
```